# Split string and drop last value

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

I have string:

```
 x = "/ls/ps/ts/00"
```

How to split and cut last value

Actual output:

```
 y = x.split("/")
 output = ['ls', 'ps', 'ts', '00']
```

Expected Output:

```
  output = /ls/ps/ts/
```

Comment: Don't you know about _slicing_? If you don't, you'd better read about it ASAP.

Comment: use slicing like `x[1:-3].split("/")` will output `['ls', 'ps', 'ts']` as per your question string.

Comment: meteor23, please read the [Python tutorial chapter on strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.path` path manipulations to great effect here:

```
import os

x = "/ls/ps/ts/00"
output = os.path.dirname(x)

print output  # prints "/ls/ps/ts"
```

Comment: sorry, expected output is /ls/ps/ts..edited question

Comment: @meteor23: Updated my answer

Comment: Maybe more explicit is to use `posixpath`  (`path` isn't *guaranteed* to split on `/`) ... also its effect on `/a/b/c//d` differs from a straight `.split("/")`)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the shortest possible solution:

```
x.rsplit("/", 1)[0] + "/"
#'/ls/ps/ts/'
```

And a regex-based:

```
import re
re.findall("(.+/)[^/]+", x)[0]
#'/ls/ps/ts/'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `split`, you can re-`join` the components. Since you want to maintain a trailing separator, you can add it back in later, or better yet, set the last element of the components to empty:

```
y = x.split('/')
y[-1] = ''
output = '/'.join(y)
```

As a one-liner:

```
output = '/'.join(s if i else '' for i, s in enumerate(x.split('/'), -x.count('/')))
```